# Cannot make release build, proguard warnings after adding kotlin coroutines and room

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

After i have added kotlin coroutines and room i am not able to make release build please help me with it.

**app/prguard-rules.pro**

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# You can control the set of applied configuration files using the
# proguardFiles setting in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
#-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

# Glide
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}


 -keep class com.google.gson.** { *; }
  -dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
  -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
  -keep public class org.jsoup.** { public *; }


#dagger
  -dontwarn com.google.errorprone.annotations.**


  #facebook


  -keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
      private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
      private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
      private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
      java.lang.Object writeReplace();
      java.lang.Object readResolve();
  }

  -keepnames class com.facebook.FacebookActivity
  -keepnames class com.facebook.CustomTabActivity

  -keep class com.facebook.login.Login


#retrofit
# Retrofit does reflection on generic parameters and InnerClass is required to use Signature.
-keepattributes Signature, InnerClasses

# Retain service method parameters when optimizing.
-keepclassmembers,allowshrinking,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit2.http.* <methods>;
}

# Ignore annotation used for build tooling.
-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement

# Ignore JSR 305 annotations for embedding nullability information.
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

# Guarded by a NoClassDefFoundError try/catch and only used when on the classpath.
-dontwarn kotlin.Unit

# Top-level functions that can only be used by Kotlin.
-dontwarn retrofit2.-KotlinExtensions



-dontwarn okio.**
# lifecycle

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-keepclassmembers enum android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event {
    <fields>;
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.GeneratedAdapter {
    <init>(...);
}

-keepclassmembers class ** {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}



#crashlytics

-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**


## Google Play Services 4.3.23 specific rules ##
## https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard ##

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

# Parceler library
-keep interface org.parceler.Parcel
-keep @org.parceler.Parcel class * { *; }
-keep class **$$Parcelable { *; }


-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

# Uncomment this to preserve the line number information for
# debugging stack traces.
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

# If you keep the line number information, uncomment this to
# hide the original source file name.
#-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile


-keep class com.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.** { *; }
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class javax.servlet.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.ietf.jgss.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn org.joda.time.**
-dontwarn org.shaded.apache.**
-dontwarn org.ietf.jgss.**

# Only necessary if you downloaded the SDK jar directly instead of from maven.
-keep class com.shaded.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }


-dontwarn kotlin.**

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final ** CREATOR;
}

-dontwarn org.conscrypt.**

-dontwarn com.google.gson.Gson$6


#Appsee
-keep class com.appsee.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.appsee.**
-keep class android.support.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.** { *; }
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep interface androidx.** { *; }


#UXCam

-keep class com.uxcam.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.uxcam.**


# For CleverTap SDK
-dontwarn com.clevertap.android.sdk.**


# ServiceLoader support
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.MainDispatcherFactory {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineExceptionHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidExceptionPreHandler {}
-keepnames class kotlinx.coroutines.android.AndroidDispatcherFactory {}

# Most of volatile fields are updated with AFU and should not be mangled
-keepclassmembernames class kotlinx.** {
    volatile <fields>;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zzhu


-dontwarn kotlin.**
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.**
-keep class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.** { *; }

-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keepclassmembers public class com.mypackage.** {
    public synthetic <methods>;
}
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}

-dontwarn android.arch.util.paging.CountedDataSource
-dontwarn android.arch.persistence.room.paging.LimitOffsetDataSource

-keep class com.facebook.stetho.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.facebook.stetho.**
```

My build.gradle file (app Module)

```
dependencies {



    // if you are not using support library, include this instead
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"

    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
    // Lifecyles, LiveData and ViewModel
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1'
    implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
    kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'

    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1"

    // ReactiveX
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroidVersion"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'

    // Retrofit2  converter
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    // Retrofit2 and RxJava2
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

    //    RxAndroid adds android specific bindings for RxJava,

    // Specifically AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() which provides a Scheduler

    // that schedules on main thread and can be used to switch between threads in Android.
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'

    //    Retrofit 2 works seamlessly with RxJava 2 using the

    // RxJava 2 adapter for Retrofit 2, add the following dependency

    // to enable the RxJava 2 compatibility
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-rxjava2-adapter:1.0.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlinVersion"
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin+Coroutines

// Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

// Coroutines
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"

    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.appsee.appsee-plugin'

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

As compared to previous release i have changed firebase version , added kotlin coroutines and added room : Compared to previous version i have added these  in code :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
 kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
 kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"
 kapt 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'(previous it was 
 16.0.5)
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.6.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.3'          implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links:16.1.8'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.0.5"            implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:16.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.0'           implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.5'

/ Room components
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
    androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"
// Lifecycle components
    kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
// Coroutines
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutines"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutines"
    implementation 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.1'

kotlin {
    experimental {
        coroutines "enable"
    }
}
```

I receive the following warnings at the time of making release build :

```
Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
         You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
         If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
         the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.

these are warnings in red in Message view :
  Warning: kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__MergeKt: can't find referenced class kotlinx.atomicfu.AtomicBoolean
```

and these are 11 of them i guess proguard is talking about htese warnings only , please please please help

Comment: Do you find solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is the most common error because of "many pre-compiled third-party libraries refer to other libraries that are not actually used and therefore not present. This works fine in debug builds, but in release builds, ProGuard expects all libraries" , so it can perform a proper static analysis.

So, You can just ignore it or write `-dontwarn` in proguard-rules.pro.

```
-dontwarn kotlinx.atomicfu.**
```

Comment: thanks but same warning , cannot make build now also

Comment: i am not able to make release build because of it  , please help

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, dont know whats the cause for error, why kotlin team left such an error:

-dontwarn kotlinx.**

Answer (score -1):

write in pro-guard Rules

-ignorewarnings

Comment: but it may create further issues , it will ignore all the warnings which might be useful too

Comment: I solved my error by adding this in pro-guard Rules. now my app is published in play store till now no issues.

Comment: I suggest you to use api not implementation

Comment: ingore warnings will not solve the error but suppress the error